# Installation of R package (tar.gz) in windows

Tags: r, package

I have a serious problem about R package installation in windows where I haven't got the administrator priveleges. For example, to install ggplot2 I did :

```
 install.packages("C:/Users/Rasengan/Downloads/ggplot2_1.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I get this error message :

```
ERROR: dependencies 'plyr', 'gtable', 'reshape2', 'scales', 'proto' are not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/ggplot2'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\library" "C:/Users/Rasengan/Downloads/ggplot2_1.0.0.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("C:/Users/Rasengan/Downloads/ggplot2_1.0.0.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Rasengan/Downloads/ggplot2_1.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

So the problem come from the pakage which depends ggplot2, what I tried is to install the different packages ('plyr', 'gtable', 'reshape2', 'scales', 'proto') one by one but the process is endless because 'plyr' depended of many or packages ...

Please could you help me, because I need shiny, ggplot2 and rCharts for my work.
Thank you in advance!

PS: the proto package doesn't depend of an other package, so I installed it easly :

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Rasengan/Downloads/proto_0.3-10.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package 'proto' ...
** package 'proto' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   'proto.Rnw' 
   'protoref.Rnw' 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (proto)
```

Comment: Add the argument `dependencies = TRUE` to your `install.packages` command.

Comment: Why are you compiling from source on Windows?